# LINQ anonymous object select property if not null

Tags: c#, linq, null

I'm looping through a list of companies and create an anonymous object by using the following linq query to retrieve the data i want to have.

The query is as following:

```
var customMail = this.db.Companies.Where(c => c.Id == company.Id)
                                     .Select(x => new { x.FromMail, x.FromName, x.Subject, x.EmailBody })
```

This object is filled correctly as a list with one result containing the correct details. But sometimes a field contains a `null` How would one filter out those null values?

I've tried the following without success:

```
var customMail = this.db.Companies.Where(c => c.Id == company.Id)
                                     .Select(x => new { x.FromMail, x.FromName, x.Subject, x.EmailBody })
                                     .Select(a => a.GetType().GetProperties()
                                                  .Where(pi => pi.GetValue(a) != null)
                                                  .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(a)));
```

I'd love to get the object without null values and then use its values within the method.

Comment: why you are using reflection? you can check each property in a Where

Comment: Since it's an annonymous object the props aren't available @EhsanSajjad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to filter out objects with any of its properties set to `null`, you can do it like this:

```
var customMail = this.db.Companies.Where(c => c.Id == company.Id)
    .Select(x => new { x.FromMail, x.FromName, x.Subject, x.EmailBody })
    .AsEnumerable() // Now you can use reflection
    .Where(
        a => a.GetType().GetProperties().All(pi => pi.GetValue(a) != null)
    );
```

This produces a list of anonymous objects with all properties set to non-null values.

Comment: Or you can just check those properties manually before Select, there are just 4 of them after all.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you don't need `.AsEnumerable()`, **.Select()** already returns one

Comment: The AsEnumerable was missing thanks! meanwhile i already fixed it without having to use reflection. I was thinking way off hahah. But nice it's doable!